# My reputation on stackoverflow seems to be missing an accepted answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-audit

When I look at the reputation tab, the graph seems to show the what I would expect to be the correct reputation, but my is set to 119.

I had been at 99 rep when I posted answers on the 2 questions that show up.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/4043/sean-lynch?tab=reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since reputation is denormalized, it can sometimes get out-of-sync with what's in the Votes table.

You can check your real reputation here: https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

From there, you can also trigger a recalc once per day that will sync up your reputation score.